# How to Save App Specific Data in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I write a program using Visual C++, which needs to save some application specific data. I just wonder:

1. Where should I store the data? It seems that there is a folder called "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming" that will be used to store app data. Then how to obtain such a folder for a specific user.
2. Is there an easy-to-follow sample that demonstrates how to do that? I just find an [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data), but it is just for C#. Is there a good sample for C++?

Thanks

Comment: Please make your questions self-contained. Don't have *just* links to entire articles on external sites. Present a summary in your own words.

Comment: [std::fstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream) may be of interest.

Comment: If you are searching for the MS specific C/C++ way - this may help: [SO: SHGetFolderPath Deprecated: What is alternative to retrieve path for Windows folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18493484/7478597)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ doesn't contain a app setting feature out of the box.

You could build something by hand, using files/streams.

You could use a library, for example, `boost::program_options` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943721/c-program-settings-boost-propertytree-or-boost-program-options) discussion).